# How can I make two columns horizontally centered?

Tags: multicolumn

This is what I currently have:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
    \begin{flushright}
        \huge\textbf{First Last}
    \end{flushright}
    \end{itemize} 
    \columnbreak
    
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
         \footnotesize \textbf{Email} & \footnotesize \href{mailto:someone@gmail.com} \\ 
         \footnotesize \textbf{Website} & \footnotesize Website \\  
         \footnotesize \textbf {LinkedIn} & \footnotesize https://linkedin.com/  \\  
         \footnotesize \textbf {Phone} & \footnotesize ()
    \end{tabular}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

And this is what I'd like to have in terms of positioning (don't necessarily want to increase the font size of "First Last"):
[image]

In a nutshell, I'm looking to horizontally balance the name column and the links column to the right of the name. How can I replicate the layout of the attached image?

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably use some kind of tabular environment, or to provide a bit more power and flexibility, something from the [tabularray package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray?lang=en), like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.6in]{geometry} % set margins
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros}% font like in picture
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % use sans font
\usepackage{tabularray}% for fancier tables
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}% for urls
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\color{black}}% remove ttshape from urls
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
% tblr with three columns, one left and vertically-middle assigned,
% one bold right aligned, one left aligned
\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l,m]>{\bfseries}rl},
    vborder{2} = {leftspace=5em},% extra space before second column break
    vborder{3} = {leftspace=1em} % extra space before third column
}
\SetCell[r=4]{c}{\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \textbf{First Last}} 
          & Email    & \href{mailto:someone@gmail.com}{someone@gmai.com}\\
          & Website  & \url{https://example.com/}\\
          & LinkedIn & \url{https://linkedin.com/in/test}\\
          & Github   & \url{https://github.com/test}
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: cv header]

Comment: Thanks so much. Should this code run successfully by itself? Or is it meant to point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's meant to point you in the right direction, though it *might* be usable as is. I didn't know what document class or other packages you were using, since you didn't post those at first. You've edited the question since I worked on that, so it's a bit unfair, but I'll add a `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` to center the table in light of your edits, but I'm not 100% what you're after with the "horizontal balancing".

Comment: Thanks. By "horizontal balancing", I meant that I wanted the name to have the same center of gravity as the links to the right of it. The image you posted is exactly what I'm looking for.